# mongodb: pull element from nested array where date is before now

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having an issue which deemed to be so simple. Given nested documents that have an expires field. One example document:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(),
   stuff: [
     {
        name: 'egg',
        expires: ISODate("2019-07-19T12:52:56.163Z")
     },
     {
        name: 'potato',
        expires: ISODate("2019-07-19T12:52:56.163Z")
     }
   ]
}
```

I thought I could use a query like that:

```
db.collection.update({"_id": ObjectId("578411d30af77c226c52b940")}, { 
  "$pull": { 
    "stuff.expires": { "$lt": ISODate() } 
  } 
});
```

possibly being able to apply that to multiple documents at once, but even when trying to update a single document I run into that error:

**Cannot use the part (expires) of (stuff.expires) to traverse the element**

I tried a ton of modifications, but I was not able to find a way to make this work or a similar example (which seems to be quite odd when searching for mongodb stuff).

If there is no way to update multiple documents at once, I would be happy if there would be a way to remove all expired items from a single document in an atomic query. The query does not need to work with older mongodb versions - latest version is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you want using this query:

```
db.collection.update({}, {
    $pull: {
        stuff: {
            expires: {
                $lt: ISODate()
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    multi: true
})
```

The above query will target all documents, and will pull every `stuff` object which expires property is lower than your `ISODate()`
the `multi:true` is the option to allow to update multiple documents